# Send Assets image data using formdata in react Native

Tags: react-native

i want to attach image that are in assets/image folder in to formdata that send for backend in my react application

```
 const imageUri = require('../../assets/images/nopic.jpg');

    const emptyImage = {
      name: "nopic.jpg",
      type: "image/jpeg",
      uri: imageUri,
    };

    form.append('attachments[]', emptyImage, "noimage");
```

i tried using this and this works fine in development mode. but when i use it in production( generated a apk  and use it in mobile) that dosent work